# In Polymer how do I top right align a paper toast

Tags: polymer

If I am not mistaken this has changed recently.
Have a look at the example here:

http://jsbin.com/fujasojilu/edit?html,output

I want the same behaviour as when it comes up from lower left, but from upper right instead.

How do I do that?

Comment: Please, provide your code in the answer, so if jsbin.com is down we can still continue knowing what you are talking about :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`paper-toast` was created following the [material design spec for snackbars & toasts](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/snackbars-toasts.html#snackbars-toasts-usage) which specifies that:

> Upon entrance, snackbars animate upwards from the bottom edge of the screen. When they appear, they do not block input.

So they don't really provide ways for us to change the direction of the animation.

However, you can make use of the `fitInto` property to make a toast appear inside a certain container and if you set that container to have a fixed position on the top of the window you can get a behavior somewhat similar to what you want.

Here's an example of how to do that:

```
<div id="container" style='position: fixed; top:60px; right:10px; width: 100%;'></div>
<paper-button raised onclick="toast0.open()">Default toast</paper-button>
<paper-toast class="fit-bottom" id="toast0" text="This toast auto-closes after 3 seconds"></paper-toast>

<script>
  toast0.fitInto = container;
</script>
```

Here's a [bin](http://jsbin.com/qajasuqixo/1/edit?html,output) showing how that looks.

If you really need the toast to come from the upper-right edge of the screen with the animation making sense with that then I'd suggest you make your own element for that.

Edit: A quick search in customelements.io showed that someone already worked on that kind of element. There's one called [toast-er](https://customelements.io/LM450N/toast-er/) which, among other things, let's you make the toast appear from any corner.

Comment: Hi Alan. Thank you very much for your response. Highly appreciated :-)